# Capture fast ingame screen in DirectX in C++ or C#

Tags: c#, c++, directx

For a project i'm trying to capture the screen of a game using c++ or c#.
I know there are a lot of solutions on the web but none of them are working 100%

I'm wondering if someone can explain how I can capture it or give me a working example..
I'm curious if it's possible in c# with sharpDX or something else...

Kind regards!

Comment: Is this a game you made using XNA, or are you trying to build an automated tool to help you capture screenshots of different applications?

Comment: It is for capturing all directX games (BF3, CoD,..) 
If i know how to capture it into a surface I know enought, the rest I already have!

Comment: You don't really have to use DirectX in this, and to be honest trying to get into the application's rendering to get frames out of it seems more difficult than just creating an application to capture the whole screen. Here's an example application that does that, and I can give a few pointers on automating it if need be: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21913/TeboScreen-Basic-C-Screen-Capture-Application

Comment: @furkle: You most certainly do need to use DirectX, especially when it has an exclusive context. Hooking into DX is fairly simple and well-documented, as is grabbing screenshots.

Comment: @RafVandelaer This will *never* be fast. To grab a screenshot, you need to force a frame to be fully rendered, then pull it from video memory to system memory. This completely collapses the GPU's pipeline, causing a visible pause.

Comment: @ssube No, for me this works in a matter of ms!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SaveDDSTextureToFile`from the DirectXTK library. It saves the current RenderTargetView Resource to a DDS file. Include `ScreenGrab.h`.

Usage:

```
ID3D11Resource* test = NULL;
mRenderTargetView->GetResource(&test);
SaveDDSTextureToFile(mContext, test, L"test.dds");
test->Release();
```